# trouble with answer buttons and next button in a javascript game

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am just learning Javascript and I am stuck with my code for a trivia quiz game.
My 'Next' button is not supposed to be shown on the main screen, only when the questions arre showing, and my answer buttons don't work. Also when the answer is correct or wrong body color shuppose to change.

I work in VS code, and checked the game both the live browser and opening it from GitHub, getting the same results.

Cache and cookies ere cleared, I restarted my laptop as well(just in case)..

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Code source: [text](https://github.com/szelezsan/QuizGame)

Here is my js code:

```
/* List of questions */
const questions = [
    {
        question: 'What is the best selling album of all time from 1976 to 2018?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Thrillers', correct: true},
            {text: 'Back in Black', correct: false},
            {text: 'Abbey Road', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Who is the lead singer of the British pop rock band Coldplay?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Guy BerryMan', correct: false},
            {text: 'Chris Martin', correct: true},
            {text: 'Will Champion', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Who is the frontman of the band 30 Seconds to Mars?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Mike Shinoda', correct: false},
            {text: 'Gerard Way', correct: false},
            {text: 'Jared Leto', correct: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'The band Muse released their first album, Showbiz, in what year?',
        answer: [
            {text: '2001', correct: false},
            {text: '2002', correct: false},
            {text: '1999', correct: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Which rap group released the album "Straight Outta Compton"?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Beastie Boys', correct: false},
            {text: 'Run-D.M.C.', correct: false},
            {text: 'N.W.A', correct: true},
        ]
    },
    {
        question: '"Some people call me the space cowboy" is the first line from what song?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Fly like an Eagle', correct: false},
            {text: 'The Joker', correct: true},
            {text: 'Fandago', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Who was featured in the song "Words" by Feint?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Anna Yvette', correct: false},
            {text: 'Veela', correct: false},
            {text: 'Laura Brehm', correct: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'From which country did the song "Gangnam Style" originate from?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'South Korea', correct: true},
            {text: 'North Korea', correct: false},
            {text: 'China', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Which 80s band is fronted by singer/guitarist Robert Smith?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'New Order', correct: false},
            {text: 'The Cure', correct: true},
            {text: 'The Smiths', correct: false}
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Which group performs the song "Crash into Me"?',
        answer: [
            {text: 'Phish', correct: false},
            {text: 'The Greatful Dead', correct: false},
            {text: 'Dave Matthews Band', correct: true}
        ]
    },
]

/* Starting game */
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton =document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement= document.getElementById('answer-buttons')



/* Shuffling question, so they will be presented in different orders each time */
let shuffledQuestions 
let currentQuestionIndex

/* Starting game, by pressing Start button */
startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    currentQuestionIndex++
    setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame(){
    /* Hiding Start button after starting the game */
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    /*Shuffling questions in random orders*/
    shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random()- .5)
    currentQuestionIndex= 0
    questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
    /* Setting up showing next question */
    setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion(){
    resetState()
    showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}


function showQuestion(question) {
    questionElement.innerText = question.question

    question.answer.forEach(answer => {
        const button= document.createElement('button')
        button.innerText= answer.text
        button.classList.add('btn')

        if (answer.correct) {
            button.dataset.correct= answer.correct
    }
    
        answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    });
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct');
    element.classList.remove('wrong');
}

function resetState() {
    clearStatusClass(document.body)
    while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild){
        answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
    const selectedButton= e.target
    const correct= selectedButton.dataset.correct
    setStatus(answerButtonsElement, correct)

    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)

    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex +1) {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
        startButton.innerText= 'Restart';
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
}}
```

I've had minor typos, which I corrected. The browser does not show any error, and I am kind of lost what to do next.

Comment: Your buttons get created, but you never attach any listeners to them for when the user selects an answer?

Comment: The next button needs the `.hide` css class to become hidden.